# Is computer opponent in video games really AI?

Tags: artificial-intelligence

In my knowledge, AI is software that is able to receive inputs and produce an output, with output changing based on its learning from provided by inputs.

As a result, is computer opponent in games such as FIFA, PES and more trivially, Ping Pong really AI algorithms?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Well, it indeed is. Maybe there is some kind of missconception about the concept of **Artificial Intelligence**.

As far as I know, close to graduating, I did an AI subject last year, and what we basically saw was path finding algorithms, among other things.

So imagine a map (not programatically speaking). Our character with AI (we will not move anything. Just execute) will search and reach all enemies before looking for the exit, or the goal, however you want to call it.

Enemies will keep moving, so the algorithm keeps searching them, even learning, if you program it to do so. That means it is not just a matter of "*GO FROM A TO B*".

That is possible thanks to some algorithms like A*, using Manhatan distance or however you want to implement those algorithms.

Imagine Fifa now, as your example. The computer, AI, has all the info at any time. Knows the position of every player. Divide the behaviour into 2 basics:

- You have the ball
- The AI has the ball
  Depending on which one, different algorithms will play. As well as depending on the difficulty set.

Same thing goes to League of Legends. If you can manage to make a "script", that would behave as an AI, as it can act without any supervision on its own, and probably do much better than most players. 
However you can configure it, you can know the position of all champions, know the Cooldown of all abilities, know from the position an ability is thrown and the first frame of direction, you can know the full path, so the AI will dodge at the minimum, etc.

As I mentioned, maybe there is a missconception of AI, like being a super extreme intelligent robot that can cook, clean, speak, and do Math homework, like a human would do. Maybe in the future.

Comment: But it just grabs some algorithm of many and produces the output, while AI requires modifying parameters (learning process)?

Comment: I'm sorry but I can't see the learning in computer engine of video games, in other words, how and what they learn?

Comment: And if they are AI why computers at each level don't improve as I keep winning against computer at beginner level

Comment: Well, my AI teacher always said the same: AI begins with something (call it `X`). Once you reach another level of complexity, we stop seeing `X` as AI, but a normal thing, and start seeing `Y` as AI. This means that what you asked about Fifa, might not seem AI to you, but it was at that moment. Now it is all about learning, by what you said, taking inputs, and applying different classifiers like Naive Bayes @ShrikeDanny

Comment: In summary, it just modifies the parameters just make it a different algorithm, doesn't it?

Comment: I'm sorry, I'm new to AI. I don't know what Naive Bayes is, but only Bayes probability

Comment: Don't worry! Well, I think you have seen the typical AI video of a super Mario videogame where the character starts without knowledge. Just basic stuff like: you have to reach the goal,  death is bad, controls are up, down, left and right. In the first try, it will just die against whatever, but in the third or forth try, it will learn and pass the level. But this is AI **now** . Before AI was winning a chess game (not even to the pros). @ShrikeDanny (and naive bayes is within the bayes probability, but basically ignoring difficult stuff so it can suppose things).

Comment: One final question, does AI make new algorithms by modifying the parameters or it chooses among different types of algorithms?

Comment: Well, I am not an AI expert. I am only close to graduating as a Sw Eng. AI by istelf, as far as I know, does not make any algorithms. I mean, atm, we do them. Maybe they learn, with different classification and predictions. i.e, a Pokemon AI has a pre-selected 6 pokemon team. Once you fight vs the ai and win, it will know the type of your pokemons and probably, as well as their attacks seen in the battle, and change those in the ai's team to ones that are stronger types: electric >water (if you had water). I encourage you to keep asking in Stack Overflow if you have more doubts! @ShrikeDanny